# Attachments missing from messages in "inbox" folder in apple mail, when using google apps

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, imap

When using mail.app with google mail (google premier apps) over imap, i have a problem where e-mails come through without showing attachments sometimes.

The odd thing is, if i look at the "All Mail" sub-folder under the "Gmail" folder(shows up further down the left side column of mail.app), the e-mail is in there and shows the attachment. Why is it then that when the e-mail is in the apple mail "inbox" view, it doesn't show the attachment?

I do have the setting in Preferences -> Accounts -> Advanced -> "Keep copies of messages for offline viewing" set to "All messages and their attachments" too. So it should be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Mail on Mountain Lion, where attachments did not show up for a message. When looking at the raw source (⌘⎇U) of the message, I also found that headers of the message were missing.

I managed to fix the issue by selecting the mailbox containing the broken email, and then using the "Rebuild" command from the "Mailbox" menu. After a short time, my emails reappeared, complete with attachments.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the rebuild command on Lion. I expected a "short time" wait, but after hours, I'm still slowly recovering the lost content of all the messages, with no attachments at all...

Now I remember why I had been reluctant to try that: instead of recovering the few missing attachments, I lost all of them (despite the proper download option in advance settings) and I'm still unsure to ultimately recover the content I was not missing.

So beware of Rebuild: with IMAP, all messages are locally discarded then (hopefully fully) downloaded again.

I just found an interesting sum up of possible fix for Apple Mail, unfortunaltely, not my issue: http://www.chriswrites.com/find-missing-emails-in-mac-os-xs-mail-app/